# SQL Server DB mail Server Failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I have a SMTP server by using which I was smoothly sending e-mails using sp db_mail.But now I am not able to send any DB mail using the same profile, all the configuration from SQL Server is fine,  but instead getting the following message in Error log 
Message
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2016-04-21T04:09:58). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).
)

P.S. By using the same SMTP server, I am able to send Mails from another IP.

The telnet thing is getting aborted when I tried it from the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: The telnet thing is getting aborted? Does it give you any message when you try to run it? It may not be configured on your machine.

Comment: It doesn't give any message, it gets connected to a new screen and then gets back to the original screen automatically.

Comment: If you can't connect with telnet sql won't be able to either; maybe anti-virus software shutting down the connection?